How to overwrite the default toolchain values
I am working on running a wrapper around the gcc compiler,
Is there a way to use the wrapper for the https://github.com/f0rmiga/gcc-toolchain/tree/main where a default is present.
_PRIVATE_ATTRS = {
    "_wrapper_sh_template": attr.label(
        default = Label("//toolchain:wrapper.sh.tpl"),
    ),
}

I need to use a my wrapper with their exec command.
I am creating a wrapper with the defs.bzl, my wrapper consists of a python script and the installation for the another executable.
::::::::::::::
defs.bzl
::::::::::::::  

def _wrapper_impl(repository_ctx):
    ::::::::::::::
    commands to install the tool in a <installation_dir>
    ::::::::::::::
    ins_dir =  repository_ctx.path(<installation_dir>)
    py_path =  repository_ctx.path(<python_script>)

   repository_ctx.template(
       "wrapper_sh", Label("//foo:wrapper_sh.tpl"),
       {"__ins_dir__":str(ins_dir),
        "__py_path__":str(py_path)},
       executable=True,
   )

   return None

gcc_toolchain = repository_rule(
    _wrapper_impl,
)

::::::::::::::
wrapper_sh.tpl
:::::::::::::: 

<the args for the tool and the functions for the tool>

exec __py_path__ __ins_dir__ <args to python> /usr/bin/gcc


I am calling this toolchain with a spearate platform
Since I am cutamising my template, I am facing difficulty to replace this functionality in the hermetic toolchain
I want to implement this wrapper when a particular config or a any parameter is called like --config=use_wrapper
Please help on this.
I tried to overwrite the template, but failed since the my other paths to be embedded on the template.
Also I want to apply this functionality only when called, so it's always failing.
